# How to set indices to get last dimension of 3D tensor with tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a 3D tensor tensor_a, `tensor_a = (510, 1, 6)` and I want to update `tensor_a[..., 0]` and `tensor_a[...,-1]`, like `tensor_a[..., 0] = 1.` in pytorch or numpy. How to set the `indices` right to achieve same outcome as `tensor_a[...,0] = 1.` in pytorch does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update) like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor_a = ...  # Some 3D tensor
idx_to_replace = 0
new_value = 1
s = tf.shape(tensor_a)
i1, i2 = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(s[0]), tf.range(s[1]), indexing='ij')
i3 = idx_to_replace * tf.ones_like(i1)
idx = tf.stack([i1, i2, i3], axis=-1)
updates = new_value * tf.ones_like(i1, dtype=tensor_a.dtype)
result = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor_a, idx, updates)
```

Although that does not work with negative indices, you would need to make it positive for example with:

```py
idx_to_replace = tf.cond(tf.less(idx_to_replace, 0),
                         lambda: idx_to_replace + s[-1],
                         lambda: idx_to_replace)
```

However, to replace the first index of the last dimension with ones, you may find it easier and quicker to simply do something like this:

```py
result = tf.concat([tf.ones_like(tensor_a[..., :1]), tensor_a[..., 1:]], axis=-1)
```

Similarly for the last dimension:

```py
result = tf.concat([tensor_a[..., :-1], tf.ones_like(tensor_a[..., -1:])], axis=-1)
```