# Setting specific entries to some value in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have the following Keras model code:

```py
def create_model():
    inputs = layers.Input((32, 32, 20))

    x = layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.ReLU()(x)
    
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(6, 1, padding='same')(x)
    outputs = outputs * inputs[..., :1]
    
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
```

I want to set some `outputs` entries to new values based on `inputs` with the following code:

```
outputs[..., 0] = tf.ones_like(inputs[..., 0]) - inputs[..., 0]
```

However, it throws an error: `TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object does not support item assignment`. I've also tried using

```
outputs = outputs[..., 0].assign(tf.ones_like(inputs[..., 0]) - inputs[..., 0])
```

but it throws a different error: `'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'assign'` (however, it works with ordinary tensorflow tensors).
So, is there a way to set some values of `outputs` to ones in the way I want?

Example of what I want to do (using arrays):

```
inputs:
[[[0 1 0 0]
  [1 1 1 0]
  [1 0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 0 1]
  [0 1 0 1]
  [1 1 1 0]]]

outputs:
[[[ 0.538 -1.141 -0.483  0.2  ]
  [-0.418  0.087 -0.915  0.433]
  [ 0.434  1.298  1.202  1.13 ]]

 [[ 0.175  1.672  0.769  0.226]
  [ 1.203  0.019  0.107  0.09 ]
  [-0.108  0.145 -0.537  0.213]]]
```

After `outputs = outputs * inputs[..., :1]` I get

```
[[[ 0.    -0.    -0.     0.   ]
  [-0.418  0.087 -0.915  0.433]
  [ 0.434  1.298  1.202  1.13 ]]

 [[ 0.175  1.672  0.769  0.226]
  [ 0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
  [-0.108  0.145 -0.537  0.213]]]
```

And with `outputs[..., 0] = tf.ones_like(inputs[..., 0]) - inputs[..., 0]` I want to get

```
[[[ 1.    -0.    -0.     0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.087 -0.915  0.433]
  [ 0.     1.298  1.202  1.13 ]]

 [[ 0.     1.672  0.769  0.226]
  [ 1.     0.     0.     0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.145 -0.537  0.213]]]
```

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @AloneTogether I've added an example

Comment: And your whole model?

Comment: @AloneTogether added it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working solution based on [tensor_scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update) and [meshgrid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/meshgrid). For more information, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453006/how-to-set-indices-to-get-last-dimension-of-3d-tensor-with-tf-tensor-scatter-nd). I also introduced a `Lambda` layer to your model to compute the outputs.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def compute_output(tensor):
    outputs, inputs = tensor 
    outputs = outputs * inputs[..., :1]

    index_1, index_2, index_3 = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(tf.shape(outputs)[0]), tf.range(tf.shape(outputs)[1]), tf.range(tf.shape(outputs)[2]), indexing='ij')
    index_4 = 0 * tf.cast(tf.ones_like(outputs[..., 0]), dtype=tf.int32)
    indices = tf.stack([index_1, index_2, index_3, index_4], axis=-1)
    return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(outputs, indices,  tf.ones_like(inputs[..., 0]) - inputs[..., 0])

def create_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((32, 32, 20))

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(12, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
    
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(6, 1, padding='same')(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(compute_output)((outputs, inputs)) 

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

dummy_data = tf.random.normal((1, 32, 32, 20))
model = create_model()
print(model(dummy_data))
```